# valueError: I/O operation on closed file while working on json file

Tags: python, json

```
import json

class file:
    def __init__(self,filename='c.json'):
        with open(filename,'r') as f:
            self.file_data = json.load(f)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.file_data}"
class crud(file):
    def __init__(self,filename='c.json'):
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            self.file = f
    #adding data
    def add(self,data):
        json.dump(data,self.file,indent=4)
        temp = self.file_data["contacts"]
        temp.append(data)



d = {"name": None, "phone": None, "email": None}

f =crud()
f.add(d)
```

Comment: Like that the file will be close immediately after the `with` block is left.

Comment: Please share the sample data of this .json file as well as the full error message with traceback

Comment: these are the data inside of c.json file
{
    "contacts": [{
            "name": "rock",
            "phone": "256555",
            "email": "abc@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "John",
            "phone": "645485548454",
            "email": null
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

`with` is context manager in python. It ensures to check if the file request to open, is if present then run the next block/section of code. After this section of code is completed, the context manager closes the connection to file.

In your case, change your code to the following

```py
import os

class crud(file):
    def __init__(self,filename='c.json'):
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            self.file = open(filename, 'w')
```

Otherwise in 'crud.add' method, at line `temp = self.file_data["contacts"]`, python interpreter will causes the error, as the file which was open, was closed immediately after `with` context is completed.

Comment: thanks , but another error raised for file_data.

Comment: @docXt Please share the complete error message.

Comment: attributeError: crud object has no attribute file_data

Comment: You are inheriting the `file` class but also redefining `__init__`, so `self.file_data` wont exist. Add a line `super().__init__()`  in your `crud`. Check https://realpython.com/python-super/

Comment: if then what should to write code in add() to append file in c.json?

Comment: As suggested, user `super` operator in your child class. Then it will work.

Kindly update you question to have all the properly details. Your question was for IO error but now it turned to attribute error. Also there are no error logs shared ! Follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask